# How to pass pagination value to drupal view programatically?

Tags: 8, views

I have a view with contextual filter and I render the view through program as below

```
$args=[$id];
$view = Views::getView('schedule');
$render_array = $view->buildRenderable('rest_export_1',$args);
$rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($render_array);
```

The view is paged with 5 results in each page. How do I pass the value to get results from the second page of the view?

Answer (score 1):

I found [setCurrentPage](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/function/ViewExecutable%3A%3AsetCurrentPage/8.2.x) more suitable for my use case

```
$view = Views::getView('schedule');
$view->setCurrentPage($pageNum);
```